# How to use NPM imports in a Node-RED node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-red

I would like to use NPM to manage dependencies for a Node-RED node, rather than including the files within the packaged node. How can I define a node, so that it uses NPM to pull in package dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you would any other NodeJS NPM module, you include a `package.json` in your node with a `dependencies` section. npmjs.org has full documentation for the package.json file format [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

The `dependencies` sections should look something like this:

```
{ "dependencies" :
  {
    "foo" : "1.0.0 - 2.9999.9999",
    "bar" : ">=1.0.2 <2.1.2",
    "baz" : ">1.0.2 <=2.3.4",
    "boo" : "2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Adding a `package.json` file also is lets you define the node so Node-RED will find it when it's npm installed, along with allowing you to have multiple nodes in one package and how to add translated text for different languages.

The Node-RED doc has a section on packaging your node up properly [here](http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/packaging)

Comment: what if you are just using a function node, instead of writing your own node?

Comment: Those nodes should be added to the `package.json` in the userDir by npm when you install them, because they need to be required in the `settings.js`